# Call one procedure in another, that was declared before it

Tags: declaration, procedure, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I have a situation:

```
procedure Compile();
begin
  //stuff
  CompileBatch();
end;

procedure CompileBatch();
begin
  //stuff
end;
```

But that obviously doesn't work, because identifier "CompileBatch" is not yet found in Compile. Are there any workarounds or do I have to rewrite all of the CompileBatch code in Compile? I'm using Free Pascal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by declaring your CompileBatch `forward`, like this:

```
procedure CompileBatch(); forward;

procedure Compile();
begin
  //stuff
  CompileBatch();
end;

procedure CompileBatch();
begin
  //stuff
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved the problem. Couldn't find anything about it and that's why I asked the question here